# Creating bash aliases via .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell

As a sysadmin I routinely rdp and ssh into remote machines for administration.

I've created a file, ${SERVER_FILE}, containing one entry per line noting the hostname and protocol to use when connecting to a given server.

Example:

```
...
server1,ssh
winsrv,rdp
...
```

Given the above entries I want the following to be created+evaluated (rdp is itself a script on my system):

```
alias server1='ssh server1' winsrv='rdp winsrv'
```

The following code, when I cut and paste the resultant output to an `alias` command, works flawlessly:

```
$ echo $(sed "s/\(.*\),\(rdp\|ssh\)/\1='\2 \1' /g" ${SERVER_FILE} | tr -d '\n')
server1='ssh server1' winsrv='rdp winsrv'

$ alias server1='ssh server1' winsrv='rdp winsrv'

$ alias
alias server1='ssh server1'
alias winsrv='rdp winsrv'
```

SO I change it to this to actually cause the aliases to be created and I get errors:

```
$ alias $(sed "s/\(.*\),\(rdp\|ssh\)/\1='\2 \1' /g" ${SERVER_FILE} | tr -d '\n')
bash: alias: server1': not found
bash: alias: winsrv': not found

$ alias 
alias server1=''\''ssh'
alias winsrv=''\''rdp'
```

Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $ eval alias $(sed "s/\(.*\),\(rdp\|ssh\)/\1='\2 \1' /g" ${SERVER_FILE} | tr -d '\n')
```

Works for me.

Comment: What about `eval "alias $(sed ...)"`? It seems more robust to me, since there is no extra stage of *word expansion*. It makes the result easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I've also incorporated Roland's quotes with excellent results.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest awk instead of sed for a much more easily readable command?

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," 
             format = "%s=\"%s %s\" " }
     $2 ~ /(rdp|ssh)/ { printf format, $1, $2, $1 }' ${SERVER_FILE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like `alias` and `echo` are interpreting some backslashes differently. This is admittedly a hack, but I would try this:

```
alias $(echo $(sed "s/\(.*\),\(rdp\|ssh\)/\1='\2 \1' /g" ${SERVER_FILE} | tr -d '\n'))
```

:-)

Comment: Hello, this generates the same errors. Output of `alias` is identical too.